# Is there a man command that lists all games in the bsdgames package?

Tags: 20.04, games

I recently installed [bsd games](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/bsdgames). But no matter what I try, I can't find any `man` command that lists them all. `man bsdgames` returns nothing. It's as if the collection only has manuals for the specific games, without giving the user any way to list said games. I'm stuck in a delightful loop of only being able to play Hunt The Wumps because it's the only game that I know is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No that is not the goal of man page. Man pages are manuals for commands, not for listing content.

See the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/bsdgames/filelist) itself.  You can also do (when it is installed):

```
dpkg -L bsdgames
```

Games listed

```
/usr/games/arithmetic
/usr/games/atc
/usr/games/backgammon
/usr/games/battlestar
/usr/games/bcd
/usr/games/boggle
/usr/games/bsdgames-adventure
/usr/games/caesar
/usr/games/canfield
/usr/games/cfscores
/usr/games/countmail
/usr/games/cribbage
/usr/games/dab
/usr/games/go-fish
/usr/games/gomoku
/usr/games/hack
/usr/games/hangman
/usr/games/hunt
/usr/games/mille
/usr/games/monop
/usr/games/morse
/usr/games/number
/usr/games/phantasia
/usr/games/pig
/usr/games/pom
/usr/games/ppt
/usr/games/primes
/usr/games/quiz
/usr/games/rain
/usr/games/random
/usr/games/robots
/usr/games/rot13
/usr/games/sail
/usr/games/snake
/usr/games/snscore
/usr/games/teachgammon
/usr/games/tetris-bsd
/usr/games/trek
/usr/games/wargames
/usr/games/worm
/usr/games/worms
/usr/games/wtf
/usr/games/wump
/usr/sbin/huntd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
apt show bsdgames
```

You're welcome!